# RW for Android 11 : /dev/block/dm-5 "Read Only File System"

Tags: android, system, root, mount

Is this possible for a rooted stock OxygenOS ROM?

I have tried all the answers given on stack and nothing seems to be working in my direction except trying to understand how Android bootstraps and links device files at boot time.

Since /dev/block/dm are all read-only at boot and this is declared in fstab. Does that mean this is impossible for Android10 and later ROM?

Comment: Look at _what kind_ of device-mapper device it is (`dmsetup` is your friend). If the OxygenOS developers are competent, you'll see it's dm_verity, which is _very_ read-only -- there's a hash of each block, and that list of hashes itself is split into hashed blocks, going up to a single root-level hash that's compiled into the kernel (or maybe set as a kernel parameter by a signed bootloader -- techniques differ); that's how Android (and generally, high-security embedded Linux systems) protect themselves against tampering.

Comment: If it's a sufficiently open-ish system that you can enable a key you own to be used to sign the kernel that's embedding the filesystem root signature (or disable the signature-checking altogether at one level or another in the chain-- often that's part of what "rooted" means here), then it's _possible_ to work around, but "possible" still may be in a context that expects you to have the typical systems-level embedded engineering skillset.

Comment: (I should have said, something like squashfs backed by dm_verity -- so squashfs itself is designed to be read-only, fast and compact; and dm_verity is intended to be a block-level anti-tamper measure that fits on top of _any_ filesystem you like)

Comment: ...of course, you can always use an overlay filesystem to make things temporarily _look_ writable; but if you want those writes to be visible in early boot... well, it's outside the scope of a reasonable Stack Overflow question, and generally will require the initramfs in use to be designed to allow it _or_ will require you to be able to replace that initramfs (and deal with whatever signatures protect it at boot time, which again is getting into implementation details that particular Android distro's developers are responsible for).

Comment: I will figure it out. but for now, when I boot to boot loader the file system is still showing up as locked. I do have dev options oem unlocking set to yes.. Very valid responses on your part, disabling verity check at boot and perhaps finding someone who has system level embedded engineering skillset. Although, it appears that my particular device is easily Rooted ( System RW ) which should mean it is a common practice and not something I would get grief about.. unfortunately I get grief for everything.

Comment: Have you checked whether it's squashfs under the dm_verity layer? If it is, it'll still be an inherently read-only filesystem even without the block-level integrity checks, so you probably want a writable layer on top. And generally, the developers _will have_ a way for an unlocked system to enable a writable layer on top, because _they_ need that to be able to quickly test their changes without a full rebuild. Anyhow -- sorry I can't help further, but I'd need to have an OxygenOS firmware image and the time to dig in, and time is hard to come by these days.